# Validation of @Html.Textbox in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I use an update action to update based on the input from the @Html.Textbox.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Shopping", new { UserID = Request.QueryString["UserID"] }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
   {               
   @Html.ValidationSummary()                
   @Html.Hidden("id", @Request.QueryString["UserID"] as string)
   @Html.Hidden("productid", item.ProductID as string)
   @Html.TextBox("Quantity", item.Quantity)   
   @Html.ValidationMessage("Quantity", "*") 
   @Html.Hidden("unitrate", item.Rate)               
   <input type="submit" value="Update" />
   }
```

and In My Model class

```
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Quantity is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Quantity")]
        [Range(2, 100, ErrorMessage = "There is not enough inventory for the product to fulfill your order.")]
        public int? Quantity { get; set; }
```

The problem is I m not getting the validation message when the textbox is empty.
But when I use @Html.TextBoxFor

```
   @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelitem => item.Quantity)
```

I am getting the validation message. and my update action is not working.

Here I have two options.

1. How to pass the textbox name "qty" in @Html.TextboxFor ?? (or)

2. How to get the validation message in @Html.Textbox() using @Html.ValidationMessage()

Any suggestions ..

EDIT :
My Update Action

```
[HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Update(string id, string productid, int Quantity, decimal unitrate)
        {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
         {
                   int _records = UpdatePrice(id, productid, Quantity, unitrate);
                    if (_records > 0)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index1", "Shopping", new { UserID = Request.QueryString["UserID"] });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("","Can Not Update");
                    }
                }
                return View("Index1");
            }
```

Comment: This is so wrong in so many ways.  You are essentially breaking all of MVC's conventions, and expecting it to still function.  MVC requires textboxes be named the same as the property you are validating.  You get the validation message in Html.TextBox by naming your textbox `Quantity`.

Comment: I tried even giving the exact name "Quantity" in textbox too. But validation message doesnt occurs. instead I get a message like this." The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'Quantity' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method in Controller"

Comment: There are any number of reasons why that might be, but you haven't given enough context to know what they are.  Is your Quantity in a nested object of your view model?  When you use the TextBoxFor method, view the source of the web page when its rendered and look at the Name attribute of the textbox.  Try naming it "item.Quantity" instead.

Comment: So why are you trying to pass qty when your Update method takes Quantity?

Comment: Yes.Quantity is a nested object in my model. I am getting item.Quantity as name when I pass in @Html.TextboxFor()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have the answer in your question, when you use

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelitem => item.Quantity)
```

you get the error message becasue the MVC model validation works on the `name` attributes as @Mystere Man said in the comments you are defying all the conventions and conventions is what MVC is all about, either change the property name in your model or use it as it is in the view if you want to leverage the MVC's model validation.

---

[Not entirely relevant but a good read.](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/07/14/model-metadata-and-validation-localization-using-conventions.aspx)